# Excel Name references to absolute sheet, how to make it relative

Tags: excel

in workbook scope

in sheet1 I define name Test = B1, then excel automatically makes it as Sheet1!B1.
now when I use the name in sheet 2. I am expecting that it would refer to B1 in sheet 2 instead of Sheet1!B1. How could I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer to `!$A$1`, this will refer to the current Worksheet.

Regards,